# jQuery Autocomplete "no result" not clickable or selectable

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

How to properly handle "no result" case in [jQuery Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) function that the "no result" is not clickable or selectable?

In the "parse" part I add "no result" item:

```
 parse: function(data) {
     var array = new Array();
     if (!data || data.length == 0) {
         array [0] = { data: { Title: "No results" }, value: "No results", result: "No results"};
     }
 }
```

So when are there no results, it shows only "No results". But it is selectable and clickable which is not OK, because this value is then passed to the text input.

**EDIT**
Complete javascript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var NoResult= "No result";
                $(function() {
                    $("#txtTextAnimal").autocomplete('<%= Url.Action("Find", "Animal") %>', {
                        dataType: 'json',
                        delay: 100,
                        parse: function(data) {
                            var rows = new Array();
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                rows[i] = { data: data[i], value: data[i].Title, result: data[i].Title };
                            }
                            if (rows.length == 0) {
                                rows[0] = { data: { Title: NoResult}, value: "", result: NoResult};
                            }
                            return rows;
                        },
                        formatItem: function(item) {
                            return item.Title;
                        }
                    }).result(function(event, item) {
                        if (item.Title != NoResult) {
                            $("#hidAnimalId").val(item.Id);
                            $("#hidAnimalId").closest("form").submit();
                        }

                    });
                });

            </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not sure which autocomplete plugin you are using, but there must be a "click" handler somewhere? In this function you could just check the for "No Results".

Alternatively, could you just set the array value to nothing when there is no data? So...

```
var array = new Array();
if (!data || data.length == 0) {
  array [0] = { data: { Title: "No results" }, value: "", result: "No results"};
}
```

Updated here:
You can use the result option...This is untested, so some tinkering will probably be needed

```
jQuery('#yourTextbox').result(function(event, data, formatted) {
  if (!data || formatted == 'No Result'){
    return false;
  } else {
    // return true or some other logic?
  }
});
```

Comment: A have updated my question with complete JS code for this functionality.

Comment: Im assuming this doesn't work still? Are you sure the item param in your result is an object? What is happening?